# Python statement giving unexpected answer

Tags: python, boolean

```
print 'a' in 'ab'
```

prints `True`, while

```
print 'a' in 'ab' == True
```

prints `False`.

Any guess why?

Comment: == operator has higher priority

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html

Comment: In python all comparison operators have equal priority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Operator chaining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) at work.

```
'a' in 'ab' == True
```

is equivalent to

```
'a' in 'ab' and 'ab' == True
```

Take a look:

```
>>> 'a' in 'ab' == True
False
>>> ('a' in 'ab') == True
True
>>> 'a' in ('ab' == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
>>> 'a' in 'ab' and 'ab' == True
False
```

From the docs linked above:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
>   to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if a, b, c, ..., y, z are expressions and op1, op2, ..., opN
>   are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent
>   to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.

The real advantage of operator chaining is that each expression is evaluated once, at most. So with `a < b < c`, `b` is only evaluated once and then compared first to `a` and secondly (if necesarry) to `c`.

As a more concrete example, lets consider the expression `0 < x < 5`. Semantically, we mean to say that *x is in the closed range [0,5]*. Python captures this by evaluating the logically equivalent expression `0 < x and x < 5`. Hope that clarifies the purpose of operator chaining somewhat.

Comment: Ah, NOW we're getting somewhere. +1 and deleted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> 'a' in 'ab' == True
False
>>> ('a' in 'ab') == True
True
```

---

Let's take a look at what the first variant *actually* means:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...     'a' in 'ab' == True
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('ab')
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 ROT_THREE           
              8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    23
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             17 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             20 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 25)
        >>   23 ROT_TWO             
             24 POP_TOP             
        >>   25 POP_TOP             
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you follow the bytecode, you will see that this equates to `'a' in 'ab' and 'ab' == True`.

- After the first two `LOAD_CONST`s, the stack consists of:

  - `'ab'`
  - `'a'`
- After `DUP_TOP`, the stack consists of:

  - `'ab'`
  - `'ab'`
  - `'a'`
- After `ROT_THREE`, the stack consists of:

  - `'ab'`
  - `'a'`
  - `'ab'`
- At this point, `in` (`COMPARE_OP`) operates on the top two elements, as in `'a' in 'ab'`. The result of this (`True`) is stored on the stack, while `'ab'` and `'a'` are popped off. Now the stack consists of:

  - `True`
  - `'ab'`
- `JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP` is the short-circuiting of `and`: if the value on top of the stack at this point is `False` we know that the entire expression will be `False`, so we skip over the second upcoming comparison. In this case, however, the top value is `True`, so we pop this value and continue on to the next comparison. Now the stack consists of:

  - `'ab'`
- `LOAD_GLOBAL` loads `True`, and `COMPARE_OP` (`==`) compares this with the remaining stack item, `'ab'`, as in `'ab' == True`. The result of this is stored on the stack, and this is the result of the entire statement.

<sup>(you can find a full list of bytecode instructions [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node57.html))</sup>

Putting it all together, we have `'a' in 'ab' and 'ab' == True`.

Now, `'ab' == True` is `False`:

```
>>> 'ab' == True
False
```

meaning the entire expression will be `False`.

Comment: why does first one returns False?

Comment: It makes some sense now.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Python treats `a <op1> b <op2> c` as `a <op1> b and b <op2> c`. For example, `0 < i < n` is true if `0 < i` *and* `i < n`. So the version without parentheses checks whether `'a' in 'ab'` (this part is true) *and* `'ab' == True` (this part is false, so the whole expression is false).

The "simple" fix is a pair of parentheses because that is an escape hatch to the behavior described above, but a better option is just not comparing with booleans explicitly.